# How can merge two arrays values in one array and save in database

Tags: php, post-meta, array

I am working on WordPress upload meta fields. When user upload images the images are sized in two dimension one is "thumb" and one is "big" and they re sized very perfectly. I save both of images dimension path in database with different meta keys Like:

for thumb image **wpc_resize_thumb_images** and for big images **wpc_resize_big_images**.

When i save images path in DB it save perfectly.

Here is my code to save them in DB:

***For big images***

```
$product_img_path[$count]['wpc_resize_big_img'] = $upload_dir['url'].'/'.$resize_img_name;
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpc_resize_big_images', $product_img_path);
```

In Database it save like this:

**meta_key**

> wpc_resize_big_images

**meta_value**

```
a:2:{i:1;a:1:{s:18:"wpc_resize_big_img";s:79:"http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Wallpaper_55-500x375.jpg";}i:2;a:1:{s:18:"wpc_resize_big_img";s:79:"http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Wallpaper_51-500x333.jpg";}}
```

***and for thumb images***

```
$product_img_path[$count]['wpc_resize_thumb_img'] = $upload_dir['url'].'/'.$resize_img_name;
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpc_resize_thumb_images', $product_img_path);
```

In Database it save like this:

**meta_key**

> wpc_resize_thumb_images

**meta_value**

```
a:2:{i:1;a:1:{s:20:"wpc_resize_thumb_img";s:79:"http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Wallpaper_55-212x159.jpg";}i:2;a:1:{s:20:"wpc_resize_thumb_img";s:79:"http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Wallpaper_51-212x141.jpg";}}
```

And when i print them they show me result like this:

**Big Imaegs**

```
$wpc_resize_big_images = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpc_resize_big_images', true);
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($wpc_resize_big_images);
echo "</pre>";
```

and result is

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [wpc_resize_thumb_img] => http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Wallpaper_55-212x159.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [wpc_resize_thumb_img] => http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Wallpaper_51-212x141.jpg
        )
)
```

**Thumb Images**

```
$wpc_resize_thumb_images = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpc_resize_thumb_images', true);
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($wpc_resize_thumb_images);
echo "</pre>;
```

and result is

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [wpc_resize_big_img] => http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Wallpaper_55-500x375.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [wpc_resize_big_img] => http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Wallpaper_51-500x333.jpg
        )
)
```

Now My question that how can i merge and save in database both dimension with one meta key and when i print the meta key it gives me result like this

**I want this**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [wpc_resize_thumb_img] => http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Wallpaper_55-212x159.jpg
            [wpc_resize_big_img] => http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Wallpaper_55-500x375.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [wpc_resize_thumb_img] => http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Wallpaper_51-212x141.jpg
            [wpc_resize_big_img] => http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Wallpaper_51-500x333.jpg
        )
)
```

If you understand the result i expecting please give the answer and please give me the tested answer. Please give me answer urgently. I hope you understand my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are saving the multidimensional array you can use this code:

```
$product_img_path[$count]['wpc_resize_thumb_img'] = $upload_dir['url'].'/'.$resize_img_name;
$product_img_path[$count]['wpc_resize_bid_img'] = $upload_dir['url'].'/'.$resize_big_img_name;
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpc_images', $product_img_path);
```

That way you can get multidimentional array like you want:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [wpc_resize_thumb_img] => http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Wallpaper_55-212x159.jpg
            [wpc_resize_big_img] => http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Wallpaper_55-500x375.jpg
        )

[2] => Array
    (
        [wpc_resize_thumb_img] => http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Wallpaper_51-212x141.jpg
        [wpc_resize_big_img] => http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Wallpaper_51-500x333.jpg
    )
)
```